# "nós nos admiramos" pode ser tanto um verbo reflexivo quanto um verbo recíproco?

Tags: verbos

"Nós nos escrevemos" é classificado por alguns como um verbo recíproco, e não reflexivo: eu escrevo para ti e tu escreves para mim.  Quanto ao verbo "admirar", sem um contexto mais detalhado, podemos dizer que poderia ser tanto reflexivo quanto recíproco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. Podemos tanto admirarmo-nos *a nós próprios* como *admirarmo-nos um ao outro*.